# How to pass Application instead of Activity context in an AndroidAnnotations-powered adapter?

Tags: android, android-annotations

My activity uses an adapter that needs a context

```
@EActivity
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Bean
    MyAdapter adapter;

}
```

The adapter in itself:

```
@EBean
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter {

    @RootContext
    Context context;

}
```

Whn I open the generated activity, I see:

```
adapter = MyAdapter_.getInstance_(getActivity());
```

The Activity context leaks memory. I wanna change it to Application Context
I could do that using a setter, I suppose, but I gotta time it somehow, so can I make AndroidAnnotations pass Application Context instead?

Comment: *The Activity context leaks memory.* If you would not do some strange stuff  in your adapter it shouldn't. If the context is leaking than it means that Adapter lives longer Activity = Strange stuff...

Comment: This is true, and I will look into it, but my question remains - how do I pass Application context to an Adapter, using AndroidAnnotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass the app `Context` with `@RootContext`, but you can inject the application object with `@App`:

```
@EApplication
public class MyApp extends Application {
  ...
}
// do not forget to register MyApp_ in the manifest

@App
MyApp myApp;
```

Then you can use that as the app `Context`.

Comment: I just found out that my generated adapter has a generated contructor that accepts the activity anyway. And the leak occurs because a `@Background` annotated method keeps running in the background when the activity is killed. Now, if I had power over this constructor I would have passed `WeakReference<Activity>` instead of the Activity itself, but I don't :(

Comment: But why are you running the method? You should add an end condition for that. BTW, there is [`@IgnoreWhen`](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/IgnoredWhenDetached#ignorewhen), but for fragments.

Comment: The method loads data from DB to display in the adapter, but sometimes if the user clicks away too quickly the activity is killed and the method keeps running.  will check out what `@IgnoreWhen` does, thanks

Comment: Well, you can check in your loop that the activity is still running or not.